# Characterising Adjugate(adjoint) of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix over a field, then [adj$(A)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) is an $n\times n$  matrix (obtained from $A$) such that $$\mathrm{adj}(A)\,A=A\,\mathrm{adj}(A)=\mathrm{det}(A)I_n.$$

**Question:** If $B$ is an $n\times n$ matrix such that $AB=BA=\mathrm{det}(A)I_n$, then is $B=\mathrm{adj}(A)$? If not, then how can we characterize $\mathrm{adj}(A)$ without using minors/cofactors etc.?

Comment: If $A$ is invertible, then obviously $B=(\det A)A^{-1}$ is unique, hence it is the adjoint matrix.

Comment: The answer is clearly no.

In particular you can take $A=0$.

Comment: @Ofir: First part of question is clear now.

Comment: For invertible matrices the answer is yes, for matrices $A$ with rank smaller than $n-1$, adj$(A)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following theorem the characterize in a sense adj$(A)$.

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. Then,

1. If rank$(A)=n$, then adj$(A)=|A|A^{-1}$.
2. If rank$(A)<n-1$, then adj$(A)=0$.
3. If rank$(A)=n-1$, then rank(adj$(A))=1$.

The first part is clear, the second is easy, for the third you need some work.